# Aggregate injections in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a class to build a report about course registration in Laravel. Following is my class:

```
class Report {

    protected $user;
    protected $course;
    protected $registration;

    public function __construct(User $user, Course $course, Registration $registration) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->course = $course;
        $this->registration = $registration;
    }

    public function build() {
        // build report
    }

}
```

Laravel will auto inject the instance of User, Course and Registration Models into Report. 
If I need more other Model classes that should be used to build the report, I will need to add more arguments to the constructor of Report.

```
class Report {

    protected $user;
    protected $course;
    protected $registration;

    public function __construct(User $user, Course $course, Registration $registration, Another1 $another1, Another2 $another2, ... ) {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->course = $course;
        $this->registration = $registration;
    }

    public function build() {
        // build report
    }

}
```

Is this a correct way ? 
Does have any other way to aggregate those classes that will be used in the Report class ? Should I use Facade Pattern to refactor it ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need that many Model injections it seems highly likely that you need to refactor your code and re-consider how a Report class is constructed.

Instead of Models, learn more about Repositories.

I recommend you also learn more regarding the Single Responsibility principle.
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel will inject new instances of these classes, you can consider doing this instead:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createInstances();
}

protected function createInstances()
{
    $this->user = new User;
    $this->course = new Course;
    $this->registration = new Registration;
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**:

Or this to resolve any dependencies of these classes:

```
protected function createInstances()
{
    $this->user = $this->app->make('User');
    $this->course = $this->app->make('Course');
    $this->registration = $this->app->make('Registration');
    ...
}
```